# How can I find a folder in a web application project asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net

I have a folder Called EG"myFolder" in a web application project.
Programmatically i need to find the path.
If I do Request.URl.AbosoluteURI it gives the full path
How do I locate myfolder in this webproject?

Example
http://localhost/mysite/myFolder

Answer (score 1):

Hai jo,

Hi,

If you want to know all the path's of the Applicatiion then it would be best to use the following:

**Application Physical**  Path: Request.PhysicalApplicationPath

**Application Path**: Request.ApplicationPath

**Current Page Path**: Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath

For the Bin folder path append the Applicaton Path + bin , and through this you can easily find out the Bin folder path.

Like all these you willl find all the Paths.

Comment: Hi,
Given a url like this http://localhost/mysite/Basket/mybasketPage.asp.
How do i get just http://localhost/mysite?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `server.mappath`

Comment: I have found this not that clever solution
result =http://" & Request.Url.Host & Request.ApplicationPath & "/" to get what I want.
Is there a better way?